# PHP soap call results from a function

Tags: php, web, soap, wsdl

I have an wsdl file with a function that returns results

```
<s:element name="RecordDataResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="RecordDataResult" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="message" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

I tried this but came up with an invalid function result.. i just want to get the value from this function

```
$response2 = $soapclient->RecordDataResponse()->RecordDataResult;
```

but get this error

```
Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Function ("RecordDataResponse") is not a valid method for this service in ...
```

any hints? using windows php and I can put data in ..

Comment: I did a get__functions and noticed there are duplicate name in functions but in the wsdl file, there is only one

array(2) { [0]=> string(56) "RecordDataResponse ImportData1(ImportData1 $parameters)" [1]=> string(56) "RecordDataResponse ImportData1(ImportData1 $parameters)" }

strange......

Comment: Please do not spread the necessary info to answer your question over comments: [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64417656/edit) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The function name is actually `ImportData1` and attribute `RecordDataResult` may or may not exist in the response. So here it is:

```php
$responseObject = $soapclient->ImportData1(/* put parameters here if any */);
if (isset($responseObject -> RecordDataResult)) 
{
    $response2 = $responseObject -> RecordDataResult;
}
else
{
    $response2 = 'N/A'; // For example
};
```